# Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014 .NET API C# find room for Instance in link

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have the following setup: File A is my architectural model with walls, rooms, furniture, ..
File B is my electro mechanical file with Lightning fixtures, Sockets, ...
File A links to file B, so that file B is a linked File.

I'm currently creating an addin in Revit which generates a list of elements that is inside a given room. Now, generating this list for elements that are in the HOST file (file A) is not that hard, just iterate all elements, check if it's an `Instance` and get the `.Room` property of that `Instance`.

However, for the Instances in the linked Document (file B), the `.Room` property always returns null.

I was hoping if somebody already stumbled against a solution for this problem.
Right now the only solution I see is to BIND the linked document, so that it is converted to a group. But, 1: I can't see a possibility to BIND a link trough the API, and 2: converting in to a group throws away all the advantages of a linked document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is use the Document.GetRoomAtPoint(XYZ point) method, and pass the origin points of the elements in the host file.

You'll need some logic to convert the coordinates between your host and linked document - see this post by Jeremy Tammik for more information: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/11/determining-host-document-location-of-a-linked-element.html

You can access the linked document through the Application.Documents property.  You'll need some logic to identify which of the loaded documents are linked documents for your host model.  You could use the TransmissionData.GetAllExternalFileReferenceIds() and TransmissionData.transmissionData.GetLastSavedReferenceData(elId) to retrieve the ExternalFileReference object and compare that with all currently loaded documents.

Comment: Doing a geometrical check is one of the solutions I had in mind. Although yours is very efficiënt! Thanks. I'm not marking it as the final answer however, becaus it doesn't make the instance's .Room property fill in correctly

Comment: The only way you'll manage to get the instance's .Room property to fill in is if you copy all of the rooms from your linked file into your host file.  The alternative (and more correct way for MEP) would be to create spaces in your model. You can use the Space Naming Utility from Autodesk to copy room names from your linked file into your newly created spaces.